# Create LAS v1.4 from scratch

Tags: r, lidr

I want to create a LAS object from scratch with number of returns up to 15 (according to LAS v1.4) like:

```
data <- data.frame(X = runif(100, 0, 100), 
                   Y = runif(100, 0, 100), 
                   Z = runif(100, 0, 20), 
                   NumberOfReturns = rep(15L, 100)) 
LAS(data)
```

However, this results in

```
Error: Invalid data: NumberOfReturns is not an unsigned integer on 3 bits
```

It appears that `lidr` LAS objects are initialized as v1.2 by default.

Is there a way to create LAS objects with v1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to create and edit the header manually. I acknowledged that lidR has not a lot of tools to create custom files format. This one could have been inferred automatically.

```r
library(lidR)

data <- data.frame(X = runif(100, 0, 100), 
                   Y = runif(100, 0, 100), 
                   Z = runif(100, 0, 20), 
                   NumberOfReturns = rep(15L, 100))

header = LASheader(data)
header@PHB[["Global Encoding"]][["WKT"]] <- TRUE
header@PHB[["Version Minor"]] <- 4L
header@PHB[["Point Data Format ID"]] <- 6L
header@PHB[["Header Size"]] <- 375L
header@PHB[["Offset to point data"]] <- 375L
LAS(data, header)
```

Notice the use of format 6. Only above 6 the number of returns is a 4 bits field.

Also you can get rid of

```r
header@PHB[["Header Size"]] <- 375L
header@PHB[["Offset to point data"]] <- 375L
```

This is not actually useful and will be infered automatically at write time.